# Storing username in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

First i´m still a newbie in PHP

I have this: 
valid.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// -------------- CHANGE VARIABLES TO SUIT YOUR ENVIRONMENT  --------------
//LDAP server address
$server = "domain.com";
//domain user to connect to LDAP
$user = ($_POST['username']);;
//user password
$psw = ($_POST['password']);
// storing session username
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
//FQDN path where search will be performed. OU - organizational unit / DC - domain component
$dn = "OU=Domain,DC=Domain,DC=com";                 
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// connecting to LDAP server
$ds=ldap_connect($server) or die ("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
$r=ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw);

if($r){



ldap_close($ds);

}else{
    echo '<div id="container" class="container_24" alpha align="center">';
    echo '<h1>La data no coincide <br /> RE-INGRESA Usuario y Clave</h1>';
    echo '</div>';
} //if $r
?>
```

My goal is to do a ldap_bind to validate that a user exists in the Microsoft Exchange directory ( i already did that ), then store in $_SESSION['username'] the value of $user to use it in my wordpress page to say hello to the user:

This goes in a line of header.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

                    echo '<div class="container" class="container_24" alpha align="center">';
                    echo '<div class="flow-text">Hola, '.$_SESSION['username'].'</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="container" class="container_24" alpha align="center">';
                    echo '<div class="flow-text">No has iniciado sesión</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

The problem is it works just one time, don´t know why, a explanation about that will be great, i tried to put the code of valid.php in functions.php but the same thing happens, what are my options?

Comment: your `valid.php` doesn't check if a POST was performed. if that script is fetched via `GET` instead, you'll be accessing undefined array indexes, which PHP will return as `null`.

Comment: When is header.php called? Before or after valid.php?

Comment: The code of valid.php is in functions.php for now @KristenWaiteJukowski.

Comment: Can you define "works just one time" and "same thing happens"? What are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: when i change of page, the variable $_SESSION['username'] is lost, i want it to be a global variable, so when i change of page it can show the message : "hola.$_SESSION['username´]"

Comment: @MarcB That was the problem my friend, it was necessary to check if a POST was performed, thanks.